# join two table with a condition in its "ON"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables

**Table1**

```
|      id    |  category     |
|------------|---------------|
|      1     |  soap         |
|      2     |  grocery      |
|      3     |  snacks       |
|      4     |  vegetables   |
|      5     |  dairy        |
|      6     |  clothes      |
|      7     |  books        |
|      8     |  shoes        |
```

**Table2**

```
|      id    |  parent_cat   |      code     |
|------------|---------------|---------------|
|      1     |  soap         |      SHP      |
|      2     |  clothes      |      CLTH     |
|      3     |  snacks       |      SNCK     |
|      4     |  books        |      BOK      |
|      5     |  others       |      OTH      |
```

I want to join them in such a way that each category would get a code
and if category is not present in other table it would get code corresponding to Others

**Desired Result**

```
|      id    |  category     |      code     |
|------------|---------------|---------------|
|      1     |  soap         |      SHP      |
|      2     |  grocery      |      OTH      |
|      3     |  snacks       |      SNCK     |
|      4     |  vegetables   |      OTH      |
|      5     |  dairy        |      OTH      |
|      6     |  clothes      |      CLTH     |
|      7     |  books        |      BOK      |
|      8     |  shoes        |      OTH      |
```

**I want the whole row of second table.**
I don't want to use sub-queries or any hard coding as it was a dynamic data so the word "other" would be different in different scenarios.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Your structure is a bit faulty - "parent_cat" should contain the category ID, not reproduce the description - that's duplication, and makes having a separate category lookup table pointless. The idea should be that if the category description text changes, you only change it in the category table. It should not be used as a foreign key field. Fix that and your problem will be a bit simpler.

Comment: 'the word "other" would be different in different scenarios.' - you are going to have to clarify what you mean by this.

Comment: it is just a dummy table structure and dummy data. i am trying to get the idea to use it in my real application.

Comment: Clearly you need a left join to get everything from table1 irresepective of whether the category exists in table2 but it's not at all clear how you would get different versions of other or what scenarios would come into play.

Comment: lets say "others" is fixed...  and now how to do it without using subquery

Answer (score 2):

You want a `LEFT JOIN` on  `Table2` with a default `code` value of `'OTH'` when no record is found in `Table2` :

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.category,
    COALESCE(t2.code, 'OTH') code,
    t2.id
FROM 
    Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.category = t2.parent_cat
```

Comment: oops...  i forgot to mention i want the whole row from the second row....

Comment: @PritamJinal : I updated my query to display `t2.id`. You already know the `parent_cat` of `Table2` (it is the same as `t1.category`, unless `t2.id` is `NULL`, in which case `parent_cat` is `NULL` as well)

Answer (score 0):

--Create First Table and load data

```
create table #t1 (id int, category varchar(30) )

insert into #t1  (id,category)
values (1, 'soap')
insert into #t1  (id,category)
values (2, 'grocery')
insert into #t1  (id,category)
values (3, 'snacks')
insert into #t1  (id,category)
values (4, 'vegetables')
insert into #t1  (id,category)
values (5, 'dairy')
insert into #t1  (id,category)
values (6, 'clothes')
insert into #t1  (id,category)
values (7, 'books')
insert into #t1  (id,category)
values (8, 'shoes')
```

-- Create Second table and load data

```
create table #t2 (id int, parent_cat varchar(30) , code varchar(10))

insert into #t2 (id, parent_cat, code)
values(1,'soap','SHP')
insert into #t2 (id, parent_cat, code)
values(2,'clothes','CLTH')
insert into #t2 (id, parent_cat, code)
values(3,'snacks','SNCK')
insert into #t2 (id, parent_cat, code)
values(4,'books','SHP')
insert into #t2 (id, parent_cat, code)
values(5,'others','OTH')
```

--Final Query

```
SELECT #t1.id, #t1.category, isnull(#t2.code, 'OTH') code  from #t1 
LEft join #t2 on #t1.category = #t2.parent_cat
```

--Output

[image]

Comment: Mysql does not have # tables. This looks like a sqlserver answer to a mysql question.

Comment: If it is mySQL then you need `IFNULL` instead of `ISNULL`.